# Permanence of Audio-CD on CD-RW

Tags: audio, cd-burning, cd-rw, audio-cd

I was going to burn some music onto a CD-RW, but pBurn warned me about doing such a thing, saying that I won't be able to burn it again.  Is that true is in trying to erase a ROM? Or can I blank it, or something?

Comment: Is it possible to get the exact error message?

Answer (score 1):

That is definitely not true. I used to do that back in the days when the cars used to have CD players.

Maybe the warning is saying that you won't be able to add more tracks to the CD unless erasing it?

Comment: Cars still have CD players

Comment: @Chris I didn't know that. I haven't driven a car produced the last five years that had one.